# ASP.Net - Azure AD authentication

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms

I am trying to implement Azure AD authentication on an ASP.Net Web Forms application I am building.

The intended flow is for the user to be prompted for a username/password from Azure which is authenticated then passed back to the application.

My authentication code is as follows

```
Private Shared app As PublicClientApplication

    Shared Sub New()

        Dim clientId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:ClientId")
        Dim redirectUri As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:RedirectUri")
        Dim tenantId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:Tenant")
        Dim authorityUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" & tenantId
        Dim scopes As String() = New String() {"https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"}



        app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithAuthority(authorityUri).WithTenantId(tenantId).WithRedirectUri(redirectUri).Build()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetAuthenticationResult() As String
        Try
            Dim scopes As String() = New String() {"https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"}

            Dim result As Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult = app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin).ExecuteAsync().Result
            Return result.Account.Username
        Catch ex As Exception
            Err.Clear()
            Return "-"
            Exit Function
        End Try

    End Function
```

```
 Private Sub BtnConnectWithAzure_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnConnectWithAzure.Click
        Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf AuthenticateUser)
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        t.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AuthenticateUser()
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Dim app As New AuthenticationManager
        Dim username As String = app.GetAuthenticationResult()

        If username <> "-" Then
            Response.Redirect(username)
        End If

    End Sub
```

However, I get the following error message:

Error type : invalid_client.

Error description: AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: ‘client_assertion’ or ‘client_secret

I have enabled ‘Allow Public Client Flows’ on the Azure AD portal but it did not seem to resolve the issue

Comment: Could you include what `platform` you selected while adding **redirect URI** in your Azure AD application?

Comment: I am not aware as I did not set up the Azure AD application myself - I have to ask the technician/engineer that did the set up. What should it be set to?

Comment: You will get that error if you selected `Web` as platform. To resolve it, you need to remove it and add **redirect URI** selecting **`Mobile and desktop applications`**  platform.

Comment: Understood - perhaps it was set as Web because this is an ASP.Net application, naturally accessible by the browser. Wouldn't the setting you specified be required for Windows interfaces/applications rather than ASP.net?

Comment: As you are using `PublicClientApplication` in your code, these settings are required. If not, make use of ConfidentialClientApplication instead of public client that allows you to add redirect URI in `Web` platform. Refer [this](https://blogs.aaddevsup.xyz/2019/08/receiving-error-aadsts7000218-the-request-body-must-contain-the-following-parameter-client_assertion-or-client_secret/)

Comment: Oh - I am using PublicClientApplication because as far as I understood, ConfidentialClientApplication does not allow for the user to enter login credentials and only works via AccessToken. 

Something else: why would the Azure AD prompt not open at all when I view the application from its production environment? When I debug the application via Visual Studio/localhost, it works fine up until the above issue. When I deploy it to the production server and try the same, the popup will not even display. Why could that be?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253768/discussion-between-sridevi-and-f-bill).

Comment: @Sridevi, for web, you should not use `Mobile and desktop applications`. Implicit grant flow is deprecated since a while now.

Comment: @F.Bill you need to generate a client_secret for this app registration and use it to redeem an access_token => authorization code flow

Comment: @Thomas I am not looking to generate an access_token but for the user to enter login credentials using an Azure prompt

Comment: When you do an oauth2 flow, this is how you authenticate user: with access_token/id_token.  User get reditected to IdP then once authenticated the IdP returns a token. If you dont wanna use a client_secret / assertion, this is called `implicit grant flow` and it has been deprecated for some time (few years) now.  Please have a look at the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/auth-oauth2

Comment: I had a read through the article and it doesn't seem to explicitly show how to integrate that onto a .net application, however - which is of course important!

Comment: @F.Bill As you already posted a follow-up query separately [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76307204/asp-net-azure-ad-authentication-follow-up), posting an answer related to the issue mentioned in this question.

Answer (score 0):

> "AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: ‘client_assertion’ or ‘client_secret"

The error usually occurs if you missed adding redirect URI in **Mobile and desktop applications** platform while using Public client application in code by enabling 'Allow Public Client Flows’ to **Yes**.

I registered one Azure AD application and added **redirect URI** in **`Web`** platform like below:

[image]

When I ran below sample code to fetch signed-in user details using **interactive flow**, I got same error as you like below:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };

var tenantId = "9d2265a5-3de9-4610-98c2-xxxxxxx";
var clientId = "7102a1a5-312f-4c91-8ca3-xxxxxxxx";

var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
};

var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);
var result = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();
Console.WriteLine(result.DisplayName);
Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
```

**Response:**

[image]

To resolve the error, remove redirect URI from `Web` platform and add it in  **Mobile and desktop applications** platform like below:

[image]

When I ran the code sample again after making above changes, I got **response** successfully like below:

```cs
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.Graph;

var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };

var tenantId = "9d2265a5-3de9-4610-98c2-xxxxxxx";
var clientId = "7102a1a5-312f-4c91-8ca3-xxxxxxxx";

var options = new InteractiveBrowserCredentialOptions
{
    TenantId = tenantId,
    ClientId = clientId,
    AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
    RedirectUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
};

var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential(options);

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential, scopes);
var result = await graphClient.Me.GetAsync();
Console.WriteLine(result.DisplayName);
Console.WriteLine(result.Id);
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, remove redirect URI from `Web` platform and add it in  **Mobile and desktop applications** platform.