# ASP.Net - Azure AD authentication - Follow up

Tags: asp.net, azure, webforms

Following up from this question...

[ASP.Net - Azure AD authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76303838/asp-net-azure-ad-authentication?noredirect=1#comment134557532_76303838)

I have managed to make the error mentioned work by setting the "Mobile and desktop applications" redirect URI as suggested. However, I cannot seem to be able to redirect back to the Redirect URI after the user has been authenticated.

Here is the code used, as also mentioned on the original question

```
Private Shared app As PublicClientApplication

    Shared Sub New()

        Dim clientId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:ClientId")
        Dim redirectUri As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:RedirectUri")
        Dim tenantId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:Tenant")
        Dim authorityUri = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" & tenantId
        Dim scopes As String() = New String() {"https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"}



        app = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithAuthority(authorityUri).WithTenantId(tenantId).WithRedirectUri(redirectUri).Build()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetAuthenticationResult() As String
        Try
            Dim scopes As String() = New String() {"https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read"}

            Dim result As Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult = app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin).ExecuteAsync().Result
            Return result.Account.Username
        Catch ex As Exception
            Err.Clear()
            Return "-"
            Exit Function
        End Try

    End Function
```

```
Private Sub BtnConnectWithAzure_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnConnectWithAzure.Click
        Dim t As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf AuthenticateUser)
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
        t.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub AuthenticateUser()
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 Or SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
        Dim app As New AuthenticationManager
        Dim username As String = app.GetAuthenticationResult()

        If username <> "-" Then
            Response.Redirect(username)
        End If

    End Sub
```

Also, when using this code, the Azure AD prompt does not open at all when deploying the application on its production server and viewing the page using its production URL.