# Azure Web App uses Azure Authentication to access the web app, how do I use this to display the email address of the user accessing the app?

Tags: python, azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-graph-api

I am currently developing an Azure Web App with Python, it uses Azure AD Authentication for site access. I want to display the current users email (I plan to use this later for access tiers also). I saw a way to get the email through use of delegated GraphAPI to get the users details. I have attempted the way below:

```
authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{subid}'
scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]

app = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret
)

token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
access_token = token_response['access_token']

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
}

response = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', headers=headers)
user_data = response.json()

print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
for key, value in user_data.items():
    print(f'{key}: {value}')
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
```

But this returns the error:

```
error: {'code': 'BadRequest', 'message': '/me request is only valid with delegated authentication flow.', 'innerError': {'date': '2023-10-20T13:05:47', 'request-id': '9b6d8130-5bf6-4711-ba90-14ccaef0b127', 'client-request-id': '9b6d8130-5bf6-4711-ba90-14ccaef0b127'}}
```

I assume that delegated would work as a user needs to sign and be authenticated on azure to access the site, or am I missing something?

Any help or alternative methods would be appreciated

GraphAPI Permissions:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The error occurred as your code use client credentials flow for generating access token  to call **`/me`** endpoint, which is not a **delegated** flow as it does not involve user interaction.

When I ran your code in my environment, I too got **same error** as below:

```py
import msal
import requests

authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId'
scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
client_id = "appId"
client_secret = "secret"

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
    client_credential=client_secret
)

token_response = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes=scope)
access_token = token_response['access_token']

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
}

response = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', headers=headers)
user_data = response.json()

print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
for key, value in user_data.items():
    print(f'{key}: {value}')
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, you need to switch to **delegated** flows like authorization code flow, interactive flow etc... that requires user to sign in for generating access token.

In my case, I used **interactive flow** by **enabling** below option and added http://localhost as **redirect URI** in mobile/desktop platform:

[image]

When I ran the below modified python code, it asked me to **pick an account** to sign in:

```py
import msal
import requests

authority = f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId'
scope = ["https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"]
client_id = "appId"


app = msal.PublicClientApplication(
    client_id,
    authority=authority,
)

token_response = app.acquire_token_interactive(scopes=scope)
access_token = token_response['access_token']

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}'
}

response = requests.get('https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', headers=headers)
user_data = response.json()

print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
for key, value in user_data.items():
    print(f'{key}: {value}')
print("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~")
```

[image]

While signing in, user will get **consent screen** to accept permissions as below:

[image]

After accepting the consent, I got the **response** with signed-in user details successfully in the output console like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, the login type method is what i was looking for. I did attempt this but when i login the login token returns this error, did I miss a step?
'error': 'invalid_client', 'error_description': "AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'

Comment: Could you include `Authentication` tab snip from your app registration to know how u added redirect URIs? Refer this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76303838/asp-net-azure-ad-authentication/76314894#76314894) that I previously answered having same issue.

Comment: That seams to have done the trick with the other thread you sent, deleting the web and replacing it with Mobile and Desktop. Although I am now getting the error "'code': 'Authorization_RequestDenied', 'message': 'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.'", but i think i just need to tweak with the GraphApi permission access?

Comment: Could you include your `API permissions` snip from Portal by editing your question?

Comment: Sure, please see the new edit

Comment: Did you get the **consent prompt** screen as I mentioned in above answer while signing in?

Comment: To call /me endpoint, your access token should have User.Read permission in `scp` claim. Could you decode the access token in [jwt.ms](https://jwt.ms) website and check `scp` claim.

Comment: Actually no, i didnt get the consent screen. I just login and get a screen saying "Authentication completed. You can close this window now.". The SCM is "scp": "email openid profile",

Comment: Your `scp` claim does not have User.Read permission. In that case, make sure to grant admin consent for User.Read permission and run the code again.

Comment: Have i not already gave it User.Read permission in the App Reg?

Comment: You added `User.Read` permission but not granted **admin consent** to that permission.

Comment: Had to chase up my Org admin, got it sorted now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi again, I was just wondering in a production setting where the web is hosting on azure web apps, what should my redirect URI be?